# Pusher is not able to connect to server on Android signed build

Tags: android, kotlin, pusher

We have integrated Pusher in our Android application. We have got the APP_KEY, SECRET_KEY for different environments and it's working fine. Until, we created a signed build and Pusher is not able to even make a connection resulting no data.

Any suggestions on how to create a signed build when Pusher is integrated?

Thanks in advance.

We have tried changing the keys for different environments and they all worked before making a signed build.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to exempt these two classes from minification:

-keep class com.pusher.client.channel.impl.message.** { *; }
-keep class com.pusher.client.user.impl.message.** { *; }

The latest 2.4.4 version of the [java websocket library](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-java) already includes this rule, so you don't need to manually add this if you're using a newer version.